# To get contents from tags in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, automation, xml-parsing

I have a xml file and want to access the details of each tag in that file and the result I'm getting is not as expected. The xml file format is as below and content in bold is one to retrieve. Any suggestions on how to proceed further would be appreciated. Thanks!

XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GLOBAL-CONSTANTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <GLOBAL-CONSTANT format-rev="1" xsi:type="globalConstEntry">
        <NAME xsi:type="string">**APL01_deviceType**</NAME>
        <VALUE xsi:type="listOrTupleBaseExpression">
            <IS-LIST xsi:type="boolean">False</IS-LIST>
            <EXPRESSION-LIST>
                <BASE-EXPRESSION format-rev="1" xsi:type="valueBaseExpression"/>
                <BASE-EXPRESSION format-rev="1" xsi:type="valueBaseExpression">
                    <VALUE xsi:type="string">**ETK**</VALUE>
                </BASE-EXPRESSION>
            </EXPRESSION-LIST>
        </VALUE>
    </GLOBAL-CONSTANT>
</GLOBAL-CONSTANTS>
```

Code tried:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse(r"C:\Desktop\ex_Test_constant.xml")
myroot = mytree.getroot()
lenof = range(len(myroot))
print(lenof)
print("len:",len(myroot))
for i in lenof:
    print(myroot[i].tag)
    for x in myroot[i]:
        print(x.tag)
        print(x.text)
```

output expected:

```
NAME: APL01_deviceType
VALUE: ETK
```

output from code:

```
range(0, 9)
len: 9
GLOBAL-CONSTANT
NAME
APL01_deviceType
VALUE
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what exact node(s) you need and what to extract from those nodes. Could you add some details?

Comment: If you want to list all nodes just use [`.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter): `print(*(f"NAME: {x.tag}\nVALUE: {x.text}" for x in myroot.iter()), sep="\n")`.

Comment: After someone has answered a question, don't edit the question to add new requirements or any other changes that invalidate any answers that have been posted. That's not how this site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your changed question after my first answer:**
This is a new question. You should not change after the answer the request. Open a new question in future, please.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

tree = ET.parse(r"xml_test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {"xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}

name_l = []
value_l = []
for globalConst in root.findall('GLOBAL-CONSTANT', ns):
    for name in globalConst.findall('.//NAME', ns):
        d = f'{{"{name.tag}":"{name.text}"}}'
        dd = json.loads(d)
        name_l.append(dd)
    for value in globalConst.findall('.//VALUE[@xsi:type="string"]', ns):
        v = f'{{"{value.tag}":"{value.text}"}}'
        dv = json.loads(v)
        value_l.append(dv)

res = list(zip(name_l, value_l))
for line in res:
    print("NAME",":",[v for k, v in line[0].items()][0],'\n',"VALUE",":",[v for k, v in line[1].items()][0])
```

Output:

```
NAME : **APL01_deviceType** 
 VALUE : **ETK**
NAME : **APL02_deviceType** 
 VALUE : **423**
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't know thats how it works. Thanks for the information and solution. Will follow the procedure in future:)

Answer (score 3):

You xml have two tags with the same name VALUE, therefore you will find a line return:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r"xml_test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

tag_list =["NAME", "VALUE"]

for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag in tag_list:
        print(elem.text)

# The problem for find() with a relative path is you have two VALUE tags, one is empty.
name = [elem.text for elem in root.iter() if elem.tag in tag_list]
print(name)
```

Output:

```
**APL01_deviceType**

            
**ETK**
['**APL01_deviceType**', '\n            ', '**ETK**']
```

But you can search with absolute xpath or for the tag attribute. Gets your requested output:

```
name = [elem.text for elem in root.findall(".//NAME")]
value = [elem.text for elem in root.findall('.//VALUE[@{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type="string"]')]
print(name[0])
print(value[0])
```

Comment: Thanks @Hermann12, it works but question is if I have file where I have type of value that I'm fetching is either of integer, string or boolean, then how to write expression to fetch value? also wanted hints to save the fetched data in form of dictionary like: name as key and value as value in dict. I'm new to python so wanted suggestions

Comment: XML is always a string, also numbers are a string. You have to transform to int(), if you would like do some math.